# Unable to create Debug Bridge

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Android studio pops up error message as soon as running the IDE.

[image]

As suggested by others, I have done followings and still see the error message.

- Kill all adb processes
- Developer option turn off and on again
- Revoke USB debug authorizations
- Manually starting the adb server does not work, it seems having conflict with Android Studio as the IDE tries to initiate its own adb.

One thing I notice in the Task Manager is that as I start the Android Studio, two adb processes get initiated then I see the error message above..

New update(March 24th, 2017):  just found a thread talking about this after spending 3 days on this issue...really Google!@? 
[Issue 258400](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=258400&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened)

Comment: first kill all adb process.

Comment: In Task manager, killed any adb process. That was first thing done. Still see the error message as start the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever stumbling upon same issue, to make a long story short, the latest version(25.0.4) has bug with Windows 7 [Issue posted in Google Android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=258400&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).. (as of March 24th, 2017).

Just revert to 25.0.3 and adb.exe runs fine.